# Is it possible to add a flash video on a fogbugz wiki page

Tags: flash, video, wiki, fogbugz

I want to add a screencast to a fogbugz wiki page. Is it possible, and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I don't believe it is possible to "embed" a screencast.  You can add it as an attachment, but I don't think that's what you're trying to do.

Also, a better place to ask FogBugz related questions is here: http://support.fogcreek.com/?fogbugz

(We aren't able to check SO every day)