# What is the difference writing code in a class and in def __init__(self) in Python?

Tags: python, class, init

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variables inside and outside of a class __init__() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537202/variables-inside-and-outside-of-a-class-init-function)

I understand that when a class is called it will run the code in `__init__` before anything. I still don't see the difference between that, and writing the code directly under the class.

For example:

```
class main():
  x = 1

  def disp(self):
    print self.x
```

```
class main():
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 1

  def disp(self):
    print self.x
```

To me, both have the same functionality. (Maybe I am missing out something.) I would like to know which is more (ahem) pythonic and why.

Comment: You didn't consider looking at the similar questions it brought up as you were typing this one?

Comment: Which? I did try searching first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537202/variables-inside-and-outside-of-a-class-init-function

Comment: Too many duplicates. So sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple key differences here, both between `__init__` and writing it just under the class, as well as what you wrote.

#### Working with `x = 1`

First, you are right--these two items of code do effectively the same thing for your purposes (specifically because we're working with `int` objects here, this would be different for mutable objects):

*Note that they don't **actually** do the same thing--please see the comments on this answer for clarification.*

```py
class main(object):
    x = 1
```

```py
class main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
```

This is why many non-standard Python libraries, like `mongoengine` and `django` models, have a standard where you create classes without using an `__init__` statement so as not to override the built-in one, but still allowing you to create class attributes, e.g., a Django example:

```py
class mymodel(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    url = models.UrlField()
```

However, as the other poster points out, there is a difference between the two in that when `x=1` is outside of the `__init__` function, it is part of the class itself even when not intialized--see **Zagorulkin Dmitry**'s answer for more detail on that.  In most cases, though, that distinction won't be relevant for you.

#### Other considerations

There are more uses for `__init__` beyond just setting variables.  The most important one offhand is the **ability to accept arguments during initialization.**  To my knowledge, there is not a way to do this without an `__init__` function.  I'll show you what I mean by this in this example.

Let's say we're creating a `Person` class, and when we create a `Person`, we supply their age, and then their birth year is automatically calculated from that for us.

```py
import datetime
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age
        self.birth_year = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=age*365)).year
```

In use:

```py
>>>joe = Person(23)
>>>joe.age
23
>>>joe.birth_year
1990
```

This wouldn't be possible without `__init__`, since we couldn't pass the initialization the `age` argument otherwise.

Comment: "these two items of code do effectively the same thing". Not really. First is a class attribute, the second produces a per instance attribute. In the example given by the OP, `x` (that is, `main.x`), and `self.x` are different variables that coexist and thus can be modified independently (except when you assign to an instance).

Comment: That's a fair point, I've updated my answer to refer to you.

Comment: All answers are arguably good. But I chose this because of the example of accepting arguments during initialization example. That is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as stated in various other questions, variables defined within the class body are attributes of the class, whereas those defined in a `def __init__(self)` block are attributes of an instance of a class.

[Difference between defining a member in init to defining it in the class body in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549722/1907098)

Answer (score 2):

As already indicated, class attributes (assigned at class level)  and instance attributes (assigned as a self attribute for example in `__init__`) are different.

On the other hand, in your first class you are defining two different attributes (class `x` and instance `x`) that coexist, but that can interfere with each other. The code below try to show the problems you can get if you define the class that way.

```
In [32]: class main():
   ....:     x = 1
   ....:     def disp(self):
   ....:         print(self.x)
   ....:

# I create 2 instances
In [33]: jim = main()
In [34]: jane = main()

# as expected...:
In [35]: main.x
Out[35]: 1

In [36]: jim.x
Out[36]: 1

In [37]: jane.x
Out[37]: 1

# now, I assign to jim attribute x
In [38]: jim.x = 5

# main class preserves its attribute value as well as jane instance  
In [39]: main.x
Out[39]: 1

In [40]: jane.x
Out[40]: 1

# But what happens if I change the class attribute ?
In [41]: main.x = 10

# nothing to jim (I overwrote before jim.x)
In [42]: jim.x
Out[42]: 5

# but jane did see the change 
In [43]: jane.x
Out[43]: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

it's different.
in first example you have `x` without initialization.

```
>>> class main():
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.x =1
...
>>> test2 = main()
>>> dir(test2)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'x']
>>> class main1():
...     x =1
...     def disp(self):
...             print self.x
...
>>> dir(main1)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'disp', 'x']
>>> dir(main)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__']
>>>
```

Comment: This is a clear example. But this is kind of a duplicated question. What should I do >.<

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the following class definition:

```
class Main:
        x = 1

        def __init__(self):
            self.y = 5
```

In this case, we can refer x directly like: `Main.x` i.e. it is a class attribute, this belongs to every objects of this class.

```
>>>Main.x
1
```

But, attribute `y` is specific to each object. We can not refer it directly like this:

```
>>> Main.y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class Main has no attribute 'y'
```

You need to instantiate an object of the class Main to refer to y:

```
>>> obj = Main()
>>> obj.y
5
```

This is similar to `static` variables in C++ and Java.

Comment: Good example, but note that OP code has hidden surprises as it declares class and instance variables with the same name `x`